# How to get pointer to new variable when using a move constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, lvalue, move-constructor

So I've got this code:

```
//movable_ptr.hpp
//Michal Cermak

template<typename T> class movable_ptr;

template<typename T> class enable_movable_ptr {
public:
    //default constructor
    enable_movable_ptr() {};

    //move constructor and assignment
    enable_movable_ptr(enable_movable_ptr<T>&& p) {
        first_ = p.getFirst();
        p.retarget_to(this);
    };
    enable_movable_ptr<T>& operator=(enable_movable_ptr<T>&& p) {
        if (this != &p)
        {
            first_ = p.getFirst();
            p.retarget_to(this);
            delete &p;
        }
        return *this;
    };

    //retargets all pointers in the linked list to a new address
    void retarget_to(T* p)
    {
        if (first_ != nullptr)
        {
            auto current = first_;
            do
            {
                current->set(p);
                current = current->getNext();
            } while (current != first_);
        }
    };

    movable_ptr<T>* getFirst() { return first_; };
    void setFirst(movable_ptr<T>* p) { first_ = p; };
private:
    movable_ptr<T>* first_ = nullptr;
};

template<typename T> class movable_ptr {
public:
    //constructors and stuff...

    //access to variables
    T* get() {return ptr_; };
    void set(T* p) { ptr_ = p; };
    movable_ptr<T>* getNext() { return next_; };
    void setNext(movable_ptr<T>* p) { next_ = p; };
    movable_ptr<T>* getPrevious() {return prev_; };
    void setPrevious(movable_ptr<T>* p) { prev_ = p; };

private:
    T* ptr_ = nullptr;
    movable_ptr<T>* next_ = this;
    movable_ptr<T>* prev_ = this;
};
```

My problem is that I need to give `T *` to `retarget_to`, but I use `retarget_to(this)` in the move constructor and assignment in `enable_movable_ptr`. That passes it `enable_movable_ptr<T> *` instead of just `T *`. The thing is, I assume that T inherits from `enable_movable_ptr`, which will never be used directly, only through the object that inherits from it. For example:

```
class A : public enable_movable_ptr<A>
{
public:
    int val;

    A(int val) : val(val) {}
};
```

And then used like this:

```
A x(42);
A y = move(x);
```

In this case, `this` would be `enable_movable_ptr<A> *`, but I need something that would give me `A *` instead. Basically I need a pointer to the lvalue of the `=` operator, while inside an overload of said operator. Is there any way to do this or am I asking for something impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't understood your question entirely, because it's not clear what you want to achieve with this `enable_movable_ptr` class. I think your way of writing `operator=` is ill-formed. You are trying to explicitly call delete on a pointer to r-value (which may firstly be allocated on stack, and moreover probably will be destroyed later anyway via some other mechanism).

I would suggest to consider copy-and-swap approach for `operator=`, this would allow you to not worry about checking if you are assigning object into itself. The signature would be `enable_movable_ptr<T>& operator=(enable_movable_ptr<T> other)` (note passing by value).

Comment: `enable_movable_ptr` is basically a shell for any object that inherits from it, allowing it to keep track of a linked list of `movable_ptr` pointers pointing to it. Moving the pointer to the first `movable_ptr` of the linked list is fine. The problem is, that I need to change where all the `movable_ptr` in the linked list are pointing to, which would be the lvalue the `operator=` is assigning stuff to. Also, I can't really change the signature, since move() returns `A &&`.

Comment: First of all, you can change the signature, because you have a move constructor. so `std::move` will return `A &&`, but move constructor can implicitly convert it into `A`.

Comment: Also now that I understand a bit better what you want: 
1) you may do static_cast<T*>(this); 2) you should consider creating a non-trivial destructor in enable_movable_ptr to update all movable_ptr objects to something like nullptr;  3) it's not clear why you have a circular list instead of plain single-linked list.

Comment: Did the static cast and it helped, now I have other problems, but that's for me(hopefully) to solve. I do have a destructor that does pretty much exactly that, just didn't add it to the code snippet since I didn't think it was needed. The list is circular basically just because it was suggested at the beginning of this assignment. I guess I could remake it to a linear one, but I don't think that would help me in any way, so I'm just gonna leave it as it is for now. Anyway, thx for the help :)